# Is this a new formula? $a + b =\left(ab - (a-1)(b-1)\right)+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's late at night and I'm tired, but I just stumbled across this while learning RSA algorithm.

$$a + b \;=\; \left(\;ab - (a-1)(b-1)\;\right)+1$$

Any chance this is new? Or, maybe, did I just somehow transform it and it is still basically the same formula? In that case, forgive me, please.

Is this useful at all, or did I just waste my time? :)

Comment: I mean, it’s true. You can use it to show that if you know the totient of a semiprime $pq$ then you know the sum $p+q$. This is why people expect breaking RSA to be as hard as factoring (although that’s an open problem).

Comment: $$a+b = (ab-(ab-a-b+1))+1$$
$$a+b = ab-ab+a+b-1+1$$
$$a+b = (ab-ab)+a+b+(1-1)$$
$$a+b = a+b$$